# Find and Copy varying text to an adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

Here goes: my first post, and I'm NOT a programmer, but I'm hoping you guys can help!

I have a list of 300 cells which all reference specific chapters of a book contained in the text of the cell.  The content of each cell varies, but the content I need to extract is consistently in this format:

"...can be found in Chapter A01: The History of The Blues."

"...can be found in Chapter D27: The Many Faces of The Blues."

I want to extract just the chapter number text "A01" or "D27", etc. and copy it into the cell adjacent to where the text was found.

In the cell, the chapter number I want to copy is always preceded by the word "Chapter" and a space, and is always followed by a colon.

I've been searching the forum for a couple of hours, and you all have already helped me figure out how to use VB to find, copy and paste the exact text match to another cell, and I did find this answer, which looked promising, but I can't figure out how to modify the details to make it work for me!

[Copy part of cells that varies in both length and content using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35893074/copy-part-of-cells-that-varies-in-both-length-and-content-using-vba)

Thanks for any help you can give me!!

Comment: You should loop on that range (see: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html), and if Instr(cell.value, "can be found in Chapter ") <> 0 then you manipulate the string that is cell.value to extract the next 3 characters of the cell.value and write them in cell.offset(1,0). String manipulation: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/string-manipulation.html . Take it step by step, posting your progress as you go (editing your question) and we can help debug!

Comment: You don't really need VBA, I think. A formula to find 'Chapter' in your string, then cutting out the relevant bit of text following should do the same thing. MID(A1,FIND("Chapter",A1,1)+8,3)

Comment: You all are awesome.  This solution, and the one below using SEARCH only gave me the first two characters of the chapter number, so I just changed the 3 to a 4 and it worked PERFECTLY.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your text is in cell A1, then paste this formula into B1:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("Chapter ",A1)+8,3)
```

You can then copy B1 to B2:B100 to extract there aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the VBA code. I'm assuming your data are in the `Range("A1:A300")`.

```
Sub ExtractChapter()
Dim Data As Range, RowData As Long, Text As String, Chapter As String

Set Data = Range("A1:A300")       'Change this depends on your data located
RowData = Data.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To RowData
    Text = Data(i)
    Chapter = Mid$(Text, InStr(Text, ":") - 3, 3)
    Data(i).Offset(0, 1) = Chapter
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

While what others are saying is true (you don't really need a VBA Macro for this), here is something that works.This will work even if your chapters are more than three characters long (variable chapter number text length).

```
Sub SEFindStrings()

Dim searchRange As range

'wherever your search range is, modify. Mine started at B4 so I used that as the start
'cell and in my Cells method I used "B". Change so it fits your data
Set searchRange = range("B4", Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp))

Dim myCell As range
Dim locationStart As Integer
Dim locationEnd As Integer
Dim keyWords As String

keyWords = "can be found in Chapter "

'Goes through, and if the cell isn't empty it finds the phrase 'can be found in Chapter '
'and then gets the next three characters.
For Each myCell In searchRange
    If myCell.Value <> "" Then
    locationStart = InStr(myCell.Value, keyWords)
        If locationStart <> 0 Then
        locationEnd = InStr(locationStart, myCell.Value, ":") - 1
            myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = (Mid(myCell.Value, _
            (locationStart + Len(keyWords)), locationEnd - Len(keyWords)))
        End If
    End If
Next myCell


End Sub
```